# MacOS: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Tags: python, pip, ctypes, pyenv

I use my python and pip in the pyenv environment, but when I try to install numpy using pip:

```
pip install numpy
```

I got the following error, does anyone know where do I get wrong?

> Collecting numpy   Using cached numpy-1.21.0.zip (10.3 MB)
> Installing build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build
> wheel ... done ERROR: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in _main
> status = self.run(options, args)   File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py",
> line 185, in wrapper
> return func(self, options, args)   File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 333, in run
> reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir   File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py",
> line 179, in resolve
> discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))   File
> "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py",
> line 362, in _resolve_one
> abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)   File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py",
> line 314, in _get_abstract_dist_for
> abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)   File
> "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 488, in prepare_linked_requirement
> req, self.req_tracker, self.finder, self.build_isolation,   File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 91, in _get_prepared_distribution
> abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)   File
> "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py",
> line 38, in prepare_distribution_metadata
> self._setup_isolation(finder)   File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py",
> line 96, in _setup_isolation
> reqs = backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()   File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py",
> line 161, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
> 'config_settings': config_settings   File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py",
> line 265, in _call_hook
> raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', '')) pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 86, in _build_backend
> obj = import_module(mod_path)   File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 983, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File "", line 983,
> in _find_and_load   File "", line 967, in
> _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked   File "", line 728, in exec_module   File
> "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "/private/var/folders/nk/t9xyqhd94zzd6br4x5rg_jj80000gn/T/pip-build-env-9l_6shz6/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 23, in 
> from setuptools.dist import Distribution   File "/private/var/folders/nk/t9xyqhd94zzd6br4x5rg_jj80000gn/T/pip-build-env-9l_6shz6/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in 
> from setuptools import windows_support   File "/private/var/folders/nk/t9xyqhd94zzd6br4x5rg_jj80000gn/T/pip-build-env-9l_6shz6/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py",
> line 2, in 
> import ctypes   File "/Users/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.7.11/lib/python3.7/ctypes/**init**.py",
> line 7, in 
> from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Comment: What version of MacOS? You have a new M1 mac or an Intel Mac?

Comment: MacBook Air(M1, 2020), mac OS Big Sur version 11.2.3, Chip Apple M1, Memory 16GB

Answer (score 5):

The following script works on my MacBook Pro (M1, 2020), MacOS: Big Sur 11.5.2. I hope this is helpful.

```
# Install x86 brew
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
alias ibrew=/usr/local/bin/brew

# Install Python 3.7
arch -x86_64 ibrew install python@3.7

# Add `python` executable (symlink to `python3`)
ln -s python3 "$(ibrew --prefix python@3.7)"/bin/python

# Symlink x86 Python 3.7 into pyenv
ln -s "$(ibrew --prefix python@3.7)" .pyenv/versions/3.7.10

# Check
pyenv local 3.7.10
python -V
# Python 3.7.10
python -c 'import _ctypes'. # works!
```

reference: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1768#issuecomment-871602950

Comment: This installs Python under Rosetta, which may not be desirable for many users on M1 Macs.

Comment: The suggested script failed for me with "Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!", I had to use the commands in https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1768#issuecomment-855523190 to get it to work

Comment: It is not installed via pyenv. It us making the symlink from globally installed to pynv folder.